# DejaDup - is it forward/backward compatible (system upgrade)

Tags: upgrade, deja-dup

Is `dejadup` forward, backward compatible - say, following a system upgrade which failed? EG I have current `dejadup` backup files in a safe partition. Intend to do (online) system upgrade 12.04 to 14.04. If problems occur, will a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 give a `dejadup` which can read the older data?

Comment: Yes, it's backwards compatible.

Comment: Yes it is but that does not mean you can restore. Always good to make a backup yourself just in case. "if problems occur, will a fresh install of ubuntu 14.04 give a dejadup which can read the older data?" it would be a no if you format the partition that has the backups ;-)